# Can directives in Angular2 capture Component onCreate and onDestroy events?

Tags: angular

Can directives in Angular2 capture component onCreate and onDestroy events? Actually I am trying to create a generic slideup and slidedown directive, so that when a component having this directive is added to DOM it slides down and when removed from the DOM it slides up. I am able to apply slideDown on component creation but slideUp animation doesn't work since the element is immediately removed from the DOM.

Comment: I expect the new Animation module currently work in progress to provide ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

> **ngOnInit**
>   Initialize the directive/component after Angular initializes the data-bound input properties.

and

> **ngOnDestroy**
>   Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

But there are others, like **ngAfterContentInit**, that might be more appropriate.

Comment: I already know this, but I have a directive applied on a component, the component's ngOnDestroy is called before the directive's ngOnDestroy and I need to execute some code in directive's ngOnDestroy which alters component's DOM (some annimation).

Comment: I just answered the question. It doesn't say anywhere that you already knew this.